# example C code for reading from a serial port using Cygwin

Tags: c, serial-port, cygwin

I am trying to create a simple serial communications program on code blocks with a Cygwin environment under Windows 7.

The program is just meant to read bytes from the serial port which is connected to a gps using three pins on the com port (TX, RX, GND)

I have a program that works (taken from an example i found) but polls till there is data from serial.

```
{

  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <termios.h>
  #include <stdio.h>


  #define BAUDRATE B115200
  #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"
  #define FALSE 0
  #define TRUE 1

  main()
  {
    int fd,c, res, x;
    struct termios oldtio,newtio;
    uint8_t buf[255];



    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

    tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */

    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;

         fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());


    /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;

    newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 1;   /* inter-character timer unused */
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;   /* blocking read until 10 chars received */

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);


    while (1) {       /* loop for input */
      res = read(fd,buf,255);   /* returns after 5 chars have been input */


      for (x=0;x<res;x++)
      {
         printf("%x ", buf[x]);
      }
       printf(":%d\n",res);

    }
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
  }
}
```

I would like to rather have an interrupt that allows me to run things in the background till something comes to the serial port.

I found an example that uses signal.h but it doesn't work? Can some help me.

```
{

  #include <termios.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <sys/signal.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>

  #define BAUDRATE B115200
  #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"
  #define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
  #define FALSE 0
  #define TRUE 1

  volatile int STOP=FALSE; 

  void signal_handler_IO (int status);   /* definition of signal handler */
  int wait_flag=TRUE;                    /* TRUE while no signal received */

  main()
  {
    int fd,c, res;
    struct termios oldtio,newtio;
    struct sigaction saio;           /* definition of signal action */
    char buf[255];

    /* open the device to be non-blocking (read will return immediatly) */
    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

    /* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
    saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
    saio.sa_mask = 0;
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    // saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
    sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

    /* allow the process to receive SIGIO */
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    /* Make the file descriptor asynchronous (the manual page says only 
       O_APPEND and O_NONBLOCK, will work with F_SETFL...) */
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);

    tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */
    /* set new port settings for canonical input processing */
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

    /* loop while waiting for input. normally we would do something
       useful here */ 
    while (STOP==FALSE) {
      printf(".\n");usleep(100000);
      /* after receiving SIGIO, wait_flag = FALSE, input is available
         and can be read */
      if (wait_flag==FALSE) { 
        res = read(fd,buf,255);
        buf[res]=0;
        printf(":%s:%d\n", buf, res);
        if (res==1) STOP=TRUE; /* stop loop if only a CR was input */
        wait_flag = TRUE;      /* wait for new input */
      }
    }
    /* restore old port settings */
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
  }

  /***************************************************************************
  * signal handler. sets wait_flag to FALSE, to indicate above loop that     *
  * characters have been received.                                           *
  ***************************************************************************/

  void signal_handler_IO (int status)
  {
    printf("received SIGIO signal.\n");
    wait_flag = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using ttyS0 instead of ttyS1.

Comment: You need to find better code examples to copy.  At least study this [Posix guide](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) and always check the return code from syscalls (including `tc[gs]etattr()`). *"I would like to rather have an interrupt..."* -- User apps don't get to use interrupts.  That's the job of the OS and device drivers. To minimize CPU overhead, your program should **block** (get suspended) during the `read()` syscall.  The OS will make the app "ready" when the read is complete.  **You need to decide if you want non-canonical or canonical I/O,**

Comment: Thanks cup, i changed it to ttyS0. Still doesnt work. 
Sawdust, if i understand correctly you say i must block it, the problem is if i block it i cant run something else while waiting for something to happen?

Comment: Also Sawdust, I have to use no canonical I/O as i need to read character by character. The GPS does not provide an eof or eol when its done with a package.

Comment: EDIT: Also Sawdust, Thanks, i changed the routine to non-canonical, I have to use non canonical I/O as i need to read character by character. The GPS does not provide an eof or eol when its done with a package.

Comment: *"if i block it i cant run something else"* -- That is what multi-threading is for.  Or use *asynchronous* read, but that is less elegant.